# Full-Text search error in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I want to use contains keyword for one table

```
 select columnname from mytable where contains(columnname, 'columntext')
```

this is giving an error as

> ERROR: Cannot use a `CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT` predicate on table or
>   indexed view 'tblmembers' because it is not full-text indexed.

what would be the error in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read these before using the contains to allow free text searching:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326035.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's because to use Full-Text searching (`CONTAINS`, `FREETEXT`, `CONTAINSTABLE`, `FREETEXTTABLE`) you need to first have a full-text index created on the table.

Use [this as a Reference for creating a Full-Text Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx).